# How to make a fading form triggered by clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a fade form when clicked in my vertical navigation bar. But I don't know what is the function. This is what I want to make.

```
   Navigation <col-md-3>
+-------------------------+
|   HOME                  |
|   LOGIN                 |
|                         | 
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

and when i click LOGIN, a form fade beneath it and anchor LOGIN become a inactive/only text

```
+-------------------------+
|   HOME                  |
|   LOGIN                 |
|   user: _____________   | 
|   pass: _____________   |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
|                         |
+-------------------------+
```

and this is my code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 no-float ">
         <li><a>HOME</a></li>
         <li><a>LOGiN</a></li>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

would you help me? I'm dont know how to use javascript and jquery.

Comment: Your question is kinda unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Praveen Kumar's answer is a complete one. But I tried to keep it simple:

```js
window.showLogIn= function (){
  console.log("Hello!");
   if ($("#myform").hasClass("myform-shown")){
     $("#myform").removeClass("myform-shown");
     }else{
     $("#myform").addClass("myform-shown");
     }
};
```

```css
.myform{
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 1s;
  margin:30px;
}
.myform-shown{
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 no-float ">
      <ul>
         <li><a>HOME</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="showLogIn()">LOGiN</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <form role="form" id="myform" class="myform">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address:</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

   </div>
```

Comment: thanks but how it  fade out when i click login again?

Comment: @amrjo I UPDATED THE CODE!. You should check whether `myform-shown` class exists by `.hasClass` and then `add` or `remove` it to toggle its presence. It's jQuery, very simple! Learn the whole api here with lots of examples: https://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is kinda unclear, but if I understand, you want to have a faded tabbed effect. I have done something like this. But before that, there are a few mistakes in your HTML:

1. You can't have an `<li>` element directly inside `<div>`.
2. Your `<a>` doesn't have the `href` attribute, which is important.

Here's what you require.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".tabs").hide();
  $(".menu a").click(function () {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($(".tabs:visible").length)
      $(".tabs:visible").fadeOut(function () {
        $($this.attr("href")).fadeIn();
      });
    else
      $($this.attr("href")).fadeIn();
    $(".menu a").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
body {background-color: #eee;}
a {text-decoration: none;}

.menu {height: 2em; overflow: hidden;}
.menu, .menu li {display: block;}
.menu li {display: inline-block;}
.menu li a {display: block; padding: 5px; background-color: #eee; border: 1px solid #999; border-radius: 3px; color: #999; padding-bottom: 10px;}
.menu li a:hover,
.menu li a.active {color: #000; background-color: #fff;}
.tabs {background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #999; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 no-float">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#login">Sign In</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tabs" id="home">
        Hello, this is home!
      </div>
      <div class="tabs" id="login">
        Username: <input type="text" /><br>
        Password: <input type="password" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks but how it  fade out when i click login again?

Comment: @amrjo When you click on login again, it fades in. Didn't you check?